# How to view Youtube Studio page source

Tags: php, web-scraping, youtube, screen-scraping

Greeting! I'm trying to developed a tool to scrape analytic data from my YouTube channel, in order to do that, I have to get the page source to get data from html id, something like that, but the problem is, when I check page source, there are not a single data from the main page I can get in there, the id, value I can see normally when inspect the page is nowhere to be found when I check the page source, did they encode it or something like that? is it even possible to view the page source? If possible then how can i do that? please let me know, thank you!
[when i inspect element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PajXm.png)
[when i view page source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SM9tJ.png)

So far i have try few online website to view page source, all the web i test work just fine

Comment: When you 'View source' you are seeing the HTML that was sent when the page was requested. If the data you are seeking is not there, that means it is loaded later via javascript (AJAX) after the page is loaded.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.